# Showing that moment estimates are asymptotically bi-variate normal

Tags: estimation, asymptotics

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be iid $\Gamma(p,1/\lambda)$ with density $g_\theta (x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)} \lambda^p x^{p-1} e^{-\lambda x}$, $x>0$, $\theta = (p,\lambda)$, $p > 0$, $\lambda > 0$. Show that the moment estimates, $\hat{\theta}$, are asymptotically bi-variate normal and give their asymptotic mean and variance-covariance matrix.

First off, I calculated that $\mathbb{E}X = \frac{p}{\lambda}$ and $\mathbb{E}X^2 = \frac{p(p+1)}{\lambda^2}$. So, setting $\bar{X} = \frac{p}{\lambda}$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^2 = \frac{p(p+1)}{\lambda^2}$, I got the moment estimates
$$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{\bar{X}}{\frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2},$$
and
$$\hat{p} = \frac{\bar{X}^2}{\frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2}.$$
Now... I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Your calculation of $E(X^2)$ appears wrong in the denominator.

Comment: @Alecos sorry, i copied it down incorrectly, but my moment estimators should still be correct...

Comment: The estimators as such converge to constants. You have to find the "variance-stabilizing factor" for each (i.e. find a scaled version of each estimator that converges to a random variable and not to a constant). This variance-stabilizing factor won't necessarily be the same for both.

Comment: You may find Slutsky's theorem useful.